# why does my script not save a layer when it encounters a " \" character in the string

Tags: python, arcpy, layers

i have some code that takes a field and finds every unique value in that field. it then creates a layer for each unique value.

The code is working ok , but it is failing when there are \ characters within the value , for example "london\bridge".

If i were to do a manual defination query and save a layer it would work . So why does it not work here ? Anyone have any ideas 
My code uses the search curosor to get the unique values and iterates through this one at a time saving out a layer .

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
## This is where the file that is to be processed is saved  
arcpy.env.workspace = "S:\\AppsData\\GIS\\PROJECT\\COMPANIES\\SHAPEFILES\\"
# The file to be processed 
Source_File = "SDE_COMPANY_LIST.shp"
# The attribute that is being looked at in this case is "COMPANY" , the company bulk list accesses all the values within the given feild in this case it is company 
Company_Bulk_Company_List = [row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(Source_File,"COMPANY")]
#the UniqueCompany variable takes all the values from the field and returns a unique set , which gives the basis for every layer to be write 
UniqueCompany = set(Company_Bulk_Company_List)
print UniqueCompany

# Getting the list out 

for company_query in UniqueCompany:

env.workspace = "S:\\AppsData\\GIS\\PROJECT\\COMPANIES\\SHAPEFILES\\"


out_layer0 = str(company_query)+"lyr"
in_layer = out_layer0
out_layer = in_layer +"lyr"

#MakeFeatureLayer variables
in_features = "SDE_COMPANY_LIST.shp"
# The attribute that is being looked at is repeated here 
where_clause = '"COMPANY" = ' + "'" + company_query + "'"
print where_clause
workspace = "S:\\AppsData\\GIS\\PROJECT\\COMPANIES\\SHAPEFILES\\"

try:
    # Execute MakeFeatureLayer
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(in_features, out_layer0, where_clause, workspace)

    # Execute SaveToLayerFile
    arcpy.SaveToLayerFile_management(in_layer, out_layer, "ABSOLUTE")
except:
     print arcpy.GetMessages()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python a backslash is an escape character. In order to put a backslash in the string you need to need to put another backslash next to it to stop it from forcing a new line.

> myString = "this is\\ a string with a backslash"

I can see your paths are set correctly but maybe the strings you are parsing only have a single backslash.

You can solve this by using a raw string.

> myRawString = r"this is a string \ with a backslash"

Also, if you are trying to create a file with a backslash in the file name, it probably wont work.

A good way to debug this problem is to put in some print statements.

Comment: Ok so at the moment the string I am passing into my where clause is a stored as a variable called company query. " * where_clause = '"' + User_Feild + '"' + " = " + "'" + company_query + "'" * How do I convert the variable into a Rawsting something like Myrawstring = '\r'+ company_query